# Force Stop Running Application Before Build in Android Studio

Tags: android

I know there is an option to "force stop running application before launching activity" (which I do have enabled) but I'm after a way to have the same program exit as soon as I click the "play" button. I believe this is what use to happen before an upgrade but ever since the upgrade I've been unable to find a way to do it.

The reason I'm after this is because before (when the app closed when I pressed the button) it was really easy to tell when the new edit of my app was up and running on the device. Now that the old version keeps running I frequently make mistakes thinking the new version is already running before it is, or more commonly, not realising the new version is ready thinking the version I am looking at is the old one.

Is there a way to bring back the behaviour I seem to remember having before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable **Instant Run** via Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment in Android Studio

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I'm afraid it hasn't worked. While the checkbox for "Instant Run" was enabled a Gradle update was required in order for it to work and disabling it hasn't made any difference. While the running app certainly does exit once the build is completed and deployed (as it did before) what I am wanting is for the app to be killed as soon as I press the button rather than several minutes later when the build completes. Is I mention I believe this use to happen before but hasn't done since an update.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Instant Run option from Settings as follows:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked as described to Diego above.

Comment: If you want app to be stopped immediately then you have to press the Red stop button. Play button will stop the app only after gradle build is finished.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm pretty sure I had it stopping automatically when I clicked play before, but I can't workout how.

Answer (score 0):

I think check thd delendencues and any error code written in any java as well as manifest file of application . I have done and my app is running.